# Visual Studio 2012 C++ solution cannot be built after project import

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++-2012

I use Visual Studio 2012 Premium (Version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5). There is a C++ solution with some projects. Everything can be built without errors. Then I import a new (but already existing) project into this solution (via right-click -> `Add` -> `Existing Project...`). If I now try to build this project or any other of the previous projects, an error message appears: `"Cannot perform requested action because a build is already in project"` (which is not true, there is no build running).

[image]

If I try to rebuild the complete solution, another message is shown: `"The operation could not be completed. Wrong parameter."`

[image]

At the same time, there are no errors or warnings in the output view at all. Rather a build summary is given, which looks OK.

```
Build Summary
-------------

Total build time: 00:12.379

========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 12 skipped, Completed at 30.09.2015 17:15:58 ==========
```

[image]

What could be wrong here? The project seems to be intact, I can open and view the properties, nothing suspicious. In fact, I imported the other 11 projects in the same way and from the same origin. Where can I get some Visual Studio log files or turn on any extended diagnostics which could point me to the right direction?
Help me, I'm stuck!

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty novel.  Restart VS first.  Then use Build > Configuration Manager and check that the Platform and Build columns are hunky-dory.  Next you'll have to tell us a lot more about the nature of these projects.  A link to the solution and project files stored on a file sharing service or github is best.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I would like to share the solution, however it contains proprietary company data even in the naming of the projects. Maybe I can anonymize it in some way or make an analogous version without all the "sensitive" parts. Concerning the nature of the projects: they are automatically generated from a domain-specific language document. There is, of course, a possibility that the generation mechanism is faulty at some point - that was our first thought. Our difficulty is to diagnose, what exactly is going wrong. The generator already delivered stable solutions in many other cases.

Comment: I have to say, omitting these *essential* details from your question is incredibly unhelpful.  If you can't share what is required to get help then you must call Microsoft for support.

Comment: Restart VS, then try rebooting machine, in case there's still some zombie processes.  If those don't help, then try building your solution from the command line using `msbuild`, to see if it 1) actually works or 2) gives some better error messages.  Also, you're not also upgrading the project from the older version by any chance?  Sometimes the upgrade process leaves some extra gunk in the *proj files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now figured out what was the reason for this behavior. The "guilty" project contained references to other projects in the solution. Other projects did, too (and worked); but the project GUID of this particular reference was not consistent with the actual GUID of the referenced project. If we view the contents of *.vcxproj file in a text editor, we find this GUID as nested `<Project>` element within `<ProjectReference>` element (s. screenshot).

[image]

As I mentioned in the comments, all projects were generated from an external specification written in a domain-specific language. There was a subtle bug in the generator mechanism, which under certain conditions led to this wrong GUID reference.

What amazes me, however, is that Visual Studio has not shown any easy-to-understand error message for such an obvious issue! If the path to the reference project is incorrect, the Studio points this out by a bold excamation mark (s. screenshot). Why not do the same in case of an invalid GUID? It took us several hours to diagnose this trifle.

[image]

Comment: By the way, can anyone tell me, whether `<Project>` is an essential part of `<ProjectReference>` at all? If only the path is contained without any GUIDs, like this `<ProjectReference Include="$(SolutionDir)/path/to/referenced/project.vcxproj"/>`, everything builds just fine.